# Using SQL - how do I match an exact number of characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-like

My task is to validate existing data in an MSSQL database.  I've got some SQL experience, but not enough, apparently.  We have a zip code field that must be either 5 or 9 digits (US zip). What we are finding in the zip field are embedded spaces and other oddities that will be prevented in the future.  I've searched enough to find the references for LIKE that leave me with this "novice approach":

```
ZIP NOT LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
AND ZIP NOT LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Is this really what I must code? Is there nothing similar to...?

```
ZIP NOT LIKE '[\d]{5}' AND ZIP NOT LIKE '[\d]{9}'
```

I will loath validating longer fields! I suppose, ultimately, both code sequences will be equally efficient (or should be).

Thanks for your help

Comment: Don't really understand what you're trying to get from this.  You should be able to select whatever is there (considering it's likely just a string), and strip out whatever characters you don't want programatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, LIKE is not regex-compatible so nothing of the sort `\d`. Although, combining a length function with a numeric function may provide an acceptable result:

```
WHERE ISNUMERIC(ZIP) <> 1 OR LEN(ZIP) NOT IN(5,9)
```

I would however not recommend it because it ISNUMERIC will return 1 for a +, - or valid currency symbol. Especially the minus sign may be prevalent in the data set, so I'd still favor your "novice" approach.

Another approach is to use:

```
ZIP NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' OR LEN(ZIP) NOT IN(5,9)
```

which will find any row where zip does not contain any character that is not 0-9 (i.e only 0-9 allowed) where the length is not 5 or 9.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways you could achieve that.

1. You can replace `[0-9]` with `_` like

   ZIP NOT LIKE '**_**'
2. USE LEN() so it's like

   LEN(ZIP) NOT IN(5,9)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `LENGTH()`

```
select * from table WHERE length(ZIP)=5;

select * from table WHERE length(ZIP)=9;
```

Answer (score 0):

To test for non-numeric values you can use `ISNUMERIC()`:

```
WHERE ISNUMERIC(ZIP) <> 1
```